# How to parse html more elegantly in PHP?

Tags: php

simple HTML code is here.

```
<table>

<tr><th>Name</th><th>Price</th><th>Country</th></tr>
<tr><td><a href="bbb/111">Apple</a></td><td>500</td><td>America</td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="bbb/222">Samsung</a></td><td>400</td><td>Korea</td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="bbb/333">Nokia</a></td><td>300</td><td>Finland</td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="bbb/444">HTC</a></td><td>200</td><td>Taiwan</td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="bbb/555">Blackberry</a></td><td>100</td><td>America</td></tr>

</table>
```

What I want to do is scrapping company name, and its price. like this.

```
Apple 500 / Samsung 400 / Nokia 300 / HTC 200 / Blackberry 100
```

So, I use php dom parser. I know there are many php parser plugin, but people say it is better to use original php parser. so I code like this.

```
$source_n = file_get_contents($html);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($source_n);
$stacks =  $dom->getElementsByTagName('table')->item(0)->textContent;
echo $stacks;
```

it is will shown many string values.... like this.

```
Name Price Country Apple 500 America Samsung 400 Korea ......
```

It is very I think, not useful coding, if I code like above, I should use explode() function, and code will more dirty than now.

**How can I scrapping more elegantly?** 
is there any easy reference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `DOMXPath::query`, gather all names first

```
$selector = new DOMXPath($dom);

$results = $selector->query('//td/a');

foreach($results as $node) {
    echo $node->nodeValue . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Then, prices after, by changing

```
$results = $selector->query('//td[2]');
```

Sandbox sample [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/87ba111232f54a8d6a71e9ddc3a170366be4acb7)

Answer (score 2):

The best solution I found for parsing html is using [symfony's Dom crawler](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html) component. Together with the css selector, you can filter HTML like you would select a class in javascript. For example to get all `p` elements, do:

```
$crawler = $crawler->filter('body > p');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use `DOMXPath::query`

```
<?php 

$html = '<table>
            <tr><th>Name</th><th>Price</th><th>Country</th></tr>
            <tr><td><a href="bbb/111">Apple</a></td><td>500</td><td>America</td></tr>
            <tr><td><a href="bbb/222">Samsung</a></td><td>400</td><td>Korea</td></tr>
            <tr><td><a href="bbb/333">Nokia</a></td><td>300</td><td>Finland</td></tr>
            <tr><td><a href="bbb/444">HTC</a></td><td>200</td><td>Taiwan</td></tr>
            <tr><td><a href="bbb/555">Blackberry</a></td><td>100</td><td>America</td></tr>
        </table>';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

//Get tables
$tables = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table');

//Get tr out of first table
$tableRows = $tables->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('tr');

//iterate over tablerows
foreach($tableRows AS $tableRow){

    //Get tableData
    $tableData = $tableRow->getElementsByTagName('td');  

    //check to see if there is tableData
    if($tableData->length >0){

        //Output first and second tableData
        echo $tableData->item(0)->nodeValue . " " . $tableData->item(1)->nodeValue . "<br>";

    }

}

?>
```